# Multi-Level One to Many in ASP MVC5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on a small project, where I have multi-level one-to-many model. But for some reason, the EF doesn't seem to understand this relationship and I receive an error when I create the MVC controller with EF.

[image: My Models]

Here are my model classes:

```
public class BusinessDomain
{
    [Key]
    public int BusinessDomainID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Business Domain Name")]
    public string DomainName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Domain Manager Name")]
    public string DomainManager { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<BusinessProcess> BusinessProcesses { get; set; }

}

 public class BusinessProcess
{ 
    public int BusinessProcessID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Business Processs Name")]
    public string ProcessName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Business Process Owner Name")]
    public string ProcessOwner { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<BusinessSubProcess> BusinessSubProcesses { get; set; }

    public int BusinessDomainID { get; set; }
    public virtual BusinessDomain BusinessDomain { get; set; }
}



 public class BusinessSubProcess
{
    public int BusinessSubProcessId { get; set; }
    public string SubProcessName { get; set; }
    public string SubProcessOwnerName { get; set; }

    public int BusinessProcessID { get; set; }
    public virtual BusinessProcess BusinessProcess { get; set; }
}
```

When I create a EF controller, I get following error: Dependent role refers to the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent role must be 1.

If I keep only two models (BusinessLine and BusinessProcess) it seems to work. I begin to wonder if ASP MVC doesnt support multilevel of one to many models?

Please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only difference that I see is that you do not include a reference to the BusinessLine object in the BusinessProcess class. You should include that and also mark it as a foreign key.

Also, you marked the BusinessSubprocessID as a foreign key to the BusinessProcess, which I believe is a mistake since you also hold a BusinessProcessID in your class.

As a side note, do you need the BusinessLineID in your subprocess class, since you can easily access it through its parent?

```
   public class BusinessLine
{
    [Key]
    public int BusinessLineID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Business Domain Name")]
    public string DomainName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Domain Manager Name")]
    public string DomainManager { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<BusinessProcess> BusinessProcesses { get; set; }

}

   public class BusinessProcess
{ 
    [Key]
    public int BusinessProcessID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Business Processs Name")]
    public string ProcessName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Business Process Owner Name")]
    public string ProcessOwner { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<BusinessSubProcess> BusinessSubProcesses { get; set; }

    public int BusinessLineID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("BusinessLineID")]
    public virtual BusinessLine BusinessLine { get; set; }
}

    public class BusinessSubProcess
{
    [Key]
    public int BusinessSubProcessId { get; set; }
    public string SubProcessName { get; set; }
    public string SubProcessOwnerName { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastChange { get; set; }

    public int BusinessProcessID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("BusinessProcessID")]
    public virtual BusinessProcess BusinessProcess { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank - Seems that I had a typo - I was calling BusinessLines, BusinessDomains before - I have updated the question accordingly now. Please if you can review again to see if this is correct?

Comment: I edited the code the way I think it should be. Try it and tell me the result.

Comment: You are awesome @Mircea Oprea! This resolved the issue. I lacked the foreign keys definitions.